# Convert cosine/sine to degree in Java

Tags: java

A simple question. I can't seem to find a function to convert a cosine to radiant or degree.
In the following code

```
public class angle{

    public static void main (String[] args){
        int a = 30;
        int b = 40;
        int y = 88;
        double c = Math.sqrt((a*a) + (b*b) - (2*a*b*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(y))));
        System.out.println("C = " + c);
        double L = ((b*b) + (c*c) - (a*a))/(2*b*c);
        System.out.println("Cos Alpha = " + L);
        double B = ((a*a) + (c*c) - (b*b))/(2*a*c);
        System.out.println("Cos Beta = " + B);

    }
}
```

I have the L and B as cosine, but I need them as a Radiant of Degree. Anyone has any idea, what function should I use?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check methods, in Math object documentation. There is some nice named method in it.

Comment: A cosine is not an angle. If you want the angle it is a cosine of then you use arccos and then presumably Math.toDegrees...

Answer (score 1):

The [Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class fits your needs. For instance the following class  compute a cosine of an angle. Have a look to all the other methods.

```
public class CosineTest{ 

       public static void main(String args[]){
         double degrees = 45.0; // put your value here
         double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees); // look to the Math class..a lot of nice stuff here

         System.out.format("The cosine of %.1f degrees is %.4f%n",
                            degrees, Math.cos(radians));

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Math.sin() &  Math.cos() function where the argument is given in radians.